# delphi firemonkey - rotate camera via sensors

Tags: delphi, mobile, camera, rotation, firemonkey

I would like to be able to rotate the camera of a 3DForm, following the movement of the sensors (gyro).

Every 100ms a timer start this method:

```
procedure TForm7.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Length(FSensors) > 0 then
    if Assigned(FSensors[0]) then
    begin
      Camera1.RotationAngle.X := OrientationSensor1.Sensor.HeadingX;
      Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := OrientationSensor1.Sensor.HeadingY;
      Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := OrientationSensor1.Sensor.HeadingZ;
    end;
end;
```

The result is incorrect because the rotation of the smartphone is not properly followed by the camera in the app (gimbal lock?)

Is there any method in the FireMonkey framework to be used that I do not know?

Doing some debugging, I noticed that the parameters Sensor.HeadingX, HeadingY and HeadingZ range from about -30 to +30 ... I would have expected values between 0 and 360, or between 0 and 2 ...

I have tried (*following an example of Embarcadero*) to use the Sensor.TiltX, TiltY and TiltZ parameters but these always return 0 on a Galaxy Note 3 and Nexus 4.

I use RAD Studio XE7 Professional on Windows 8.1.

Comment: If you take a look at documentation you will see that HeadingX, HeadingY and HeadingZ return their value in MIcroTeslas and not Degrees. This means that you will have to do your own math to convert that into Degrees. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that so I can't help you any further. But I gues there might be an example somewhere on the web that use these.

Comment: Thank you SilverWarior, I'll try it.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it

Answer (score 0):

I found this code snippet on an Embarcadero example:

```
      {$IFDEF ANDROID} //In Android, Tilt property is returned as vector
        Camera1.RotationAngle.X := FSensor.TiltX * 360;
        Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := FSensor.TiltY * 360;
        Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := FSensor.TiltZ * 360;
      {$ELSE} //In other platforms, Tilt property is returned as degree
        Camera1.RotationAngle.X := FSensor.TiltX;
        Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := FSensor.TiltY;
        Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := FSensor.TiltZ;
      {$ENDIF}
```